# Retrieving historical of availability using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a *historical table* to store the availability of a dispositive

The table has more than 10 millions rows.

```
CREATE TABLE HIST_AVAILABLE_DISP
(
  DISP          VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  STATUS        CHAR(1 BYTE),
  DATE_CHECK    DATE
)
```

and I have the tables with the dispositives:

```
CREATE TABLE DISPOSITIVE
(
  ID               INTEGER                      NOT NULL,
  ID_TYPE          INTEGER                      NOT NULL,
  DISP             VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  ........
)
```

I have a routine to check wheather the dispositive is available or not.
If is available, I insert a row with `DATE_CHECK = sysdate` and `STATUS = 1`. If is not available, I insert a row "saying that I checked the dispositive but got no response (a.k.a unavailable) with `DATE_CHECK = sysdate` and `STATUS = 0`, both statement in `HIST_AVAILABLE_DISP`.

I need to get all dispositives that has been unavailable for more than 24h.
Here is what I did:

```
SELECT 'Unavailable24h' type, id_type, disp
  FROM (SELECT   r.id_type, r.disp, MAX (h.DATE_CHECK) last_check,
                 last_availability, ROUND ((MAX (h.DATE_CHECK) - last_availability), 0) days_out
            FROM HIST_AVAILABLE_DISP h
                 INNER JOIN
                 (SELECT   disp, MAX (DATE_CHECK) last_availability
                      FROM HIST_AVAILABLE_DISP h
                     WHERE h.status = 1
                  GROUP BY disp) d ON (d.disp = h.disp)
                 INNER JOIN DISPOSITIVE r ON (h.disp = r.disp)
           WHERE r.id_type IN (1, 2)
             AND h.DATA > SYSDATE - 1
        GROUP BY r.disp, r.id_type) t1
 WHERE days_out * 24 > 24
```

The point is that it takes about 20 seconds to one select... since this query fetchs the entire table (***table access full***) and as I said, it has more than 10 millions rows.

Is there a way to make a faster query?
What I need after that is to check the availability of all dispositives from the last 365 days (listing day - count of unavailable dispositives) at once

**EDIT**

Suposing that I have only two dispositives (A and B) :

and doing `select * from HIST_AVAILABLE_DISP`:

```
DISP    STATUS     DATE_CHECK


A    0    15/02/2016 00:00:00
A    1    17/02/2016 00:00:00
A    0    18/02/2016 00:00:00
A    0    18/02/2016 00:30:00
....
A    1    19/02/2016 00:00:00
```

My output would be:

```
Day         count_unavailable

16/02/2016  1
17/02/2016  0
18/02/2016  1
19/02/2016  0
```

Explain Plain:

```
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 16,545  Bytes: 153,66  Cardinality: 2,561                       
    10 FILTER                   
        9 HASH GROUP BY  Cost: 16,545  Bytes: 153,66  Cardinality: 2,561                
            8 HASH JOIN  Cost: 16,542  Bytes: 3.072.120  Cardinality: 51,202            
                3 VIEW USER. Cost: 9,527  Bytes: 15,929  Cardinality: 937       
                    2 HASH GROUP BY  Cost: 9,527  Bytes: 14,992  Cardinality: 937   
                        1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE USER.HIST_AVAILABLE_DISP Cost: 9,168  Bytes: 80.954.416  Cardinality: 5.059.651  
                7 HASH JOIN  Cost: 7,014  Bytes: 2.201.686  Cardinality: 51,202         
                    4 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE USER.DISPOSITIVE Cost: 7  Bytes: 24,612  Cardinality: 879     
                    6 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE USER.HIST_AVAILABLE_DISP Cost: 7,006  Bytes: 819,075  Cardinality: 54,605   
                        5 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX USER.IDX_DATA Cost: 315  Cardinality: 54,605
```

Predicate Information:

```
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROUND(MAX("H"."DATE_CHECK")-"D"."DATE_CHECK",0)*24>24)
   3 - access("D"."DISP"="H"."DISP")
   6 - filter(TO_NUMBER("H"."STATUS")=1)
   7 - access("H"."DISP"="D"."DISP")
   8 - filter("D"."KEY_TYPE"= 1 AND ("D"."ID_TYPE"=1 OR "D"."ID_TYPE"=2))
  10 - access("H"."DATE_CHECK">SYSDATE@!-1)
```

Comment: Basically I have to get the max(date_check) of status = 0 - max(date_check) of status = 1

Comment: I'm sorry... just edited now...0 = unavailable and checked.. 1 = available and checked

Comment: Alex, I need to get all dispositives that was unavailable for more than 24h.. But I think there is a better solution above what I did..

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT ..... your query ...` and then `SELECT * FROM Table(DBMS_XPLAN.Display)`. Please copy a result of last query (as a text - not bitmap !!!) and append it to the question. Thanks.

Comment: The exact desired output: day (dd/mm/yyyy) - count_of_unavailable_disp for each day in the last 365 days..

Comment: unavailable for more than 24 hours means: The dispositive X was last checked with status = 0 on date SYSDATE but "got response" (status = 1) on date SYSDATE-2, for example... It's a dispositive that has status = 0 and status = 1 and  the intervals of dates of them > 24h. So if TODAY my dispositive got unavailable for 48h, YESTERDAY it was unavailable for 24 but the day before, it was available). Suposing that it has only this dispositive, I should have: `3_days_ago | 0 unavailable` `2_days_ago | 0 unavailable` `1_days_ago | 1 unavailable` `0_days_ago | 1 unavailable`.. got it?

Comment: I just edited the question now with a better explanation... those checks are generated at several scheduled times a day.... randomly

Comment: I'd use partitions by range so you'd only use data from the relevant months.

Comment: Just added the `Explain Plain`... take a look

Comment: Is this really a whole explain plan ? There is missing "predicate information" which is printed at the bottom of the table (but only if the explain is generated using a method from my previous comment).

Comment: I'm sorry kordirko... just added now.

Comment: One issue in the explain plan is here: `1 - filter(ROUND(MAX("H"."DATE_CHECK")-"D"."DATE_CHECK",0)*24>24)`. The final condition `WHERE days_out * 24 > 24` is pushed down to the subqueries and probably causes a full table scan on HIST_AVAILABLE_DISP. You need to rewrite this condition somehow, The other issue is here: `filter(TO_NUMBER("H"."STATUS")=1)` status is varchar.Use '1' (string) instead of 1 in the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query - get all the `DISP` that have not been available in the last 24 hours**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   DISPOSITIVE d
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'X'
                    FROM HIST_AVAILABLE_DISP h
                    WHERE STATUS = 1
                    AND   DATE_CHECK > SYSDATE - 1
                    AND   d.DISP = h.DISP );
```

**Query - get all the `DISP` that have not been available in the last but have been found unavailable**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   DISPOSITIVE d
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'X'
                    FROM HIST_AVAILABLE_DISP h
                    WHERE STATUS = 1
                    AND   DATE_CHECK > SYSDATE - 1
                    AND   d.DISP = h.DISP )
AND    EXISTS     ( SELECT 'X'
                    FROM HIST_AVAILABLE_DISP h
                    WHERE STATUS = 0
                    AND   DATE_CHECK > SYSDATE - 1
                    AND   d.DISP = h.DISP );
```

**Query - check for each 24 hour period of the last year**:

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS Start_of_24hr_period,
       d.*
FROM   DISPOSITIVE d
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -12 ) + LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -12 ) + LEVEL <= SYSDATE
           )
           AS SYS.ODCIDATELIST
         )
       ) y
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'X'
                    FROM HIST_AVAILABLE_DISP h
                    WHERE STATUS = 1
                    AND   DATE_CHECK  > y.COLUMN_VALUE - 1
                    AND   DATE_CHECK <= y.COLUMN_VALUE
                    AND   d.DISP = h.DISP )
AND    EXISTS     ( SELECT 'X'
                    FROM HIST_AVAILABLE_DISP h
                    WHERE STATUS = 0
                    AND   DATE_CHECK  > y.COLUMN_VALUE - 1
                    AND   DATE_CHECK <= y.COLUMN_VALUE
                    AND   d.DISP = h.DISP );
```

If you want to check full days (rather than 24 hours periods) then change:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -12 ) + LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -12 ) + LEVEL <= SYSDATE
```

To:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + 1, -12 ) + LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + 1, -12 ) + LEVEL <= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + 1
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer... i'm running the bigger query to see what returns... but I need to get all dispositives that is unavailable for more than 24h...... my first select has a difference of values with your query.... I don't see where you get the difference between the dates of availability (status = 0 and status = 1)

Comment: Why do you need to get the difference between the dates for different availabilities to know that it has been unavailable for more than 24 hours? You only need to know that within the last 24 hours that it has never been available and that it has at least once been unavailable.

Comment: I have to get the biggest date when it was checked (`status = 0`) and the biggest date when it was available (`status = 1`) and check if the difference is bigger than 24